# find unique entries inside a multidimensional javascript array, order important dependent on level

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array, unique

What would be the most elegant solution to find all unique first level entries inside a multidimensional javascript array? There is only one important rule: **the order of the entries is important only on the first level, but not important on the second level**

For example, for the following array the script should return 4 unique entries (the first, the third, the fourth and the fifth):

```
[
  [ [],[22],[1,13,17],[12],[] ], 
  [ [],[22],[17,13,1],[12],[] ], 
  [ [],[12],[1,13,17],[22],[] ], 
  [ [11],[12],[13],[14],[15] ], 
  [ [15],[14],[13],[12],[11] ]
]
```

PS. jQuery can be used as well.

Comment: is the number of level fixed or not? I see here that the there is 3 levels, is it always 3?

Comment: the number of levels is fixed. please excuse not taking into count the very first level, so my BOLD info would read actually different, LEVELs incremented by +1

Comment: i checked all three scripts, and for my reference array, only the answer of JJ Geewax resulted to the correct uniques. the reference array can be found inside this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4gsedoct/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not all that worried about performance and just need something that works, you could use the constant depth you mentioned along with the string representation as a "fingerprint" of sorts (akin to Java's `hashcode`).

Then you use a `Set` to keep track of items you've not seen before, and add only those that are new.

```
function getUnique(rows) {
  let unique = new Set();
  let results = [];
  for (let row of rows) {
    // Fingerprint is the string representation of the row,
    // with the inner-level sorted (as order doesn't matter).
    // E.g., fingerprint of [ [8], [3, 2, 1], [9] ] is '[[8],[1,2,3],[9]]'
    let fingerprint = JSON.stringify(row.map((cells) => {
      return cells.concat().sort();  // Use concat to avoid sorting in place.
    }));

    // If we haven't seen this fingerprint before,
    // add to the filter and the results list.
    if (!unique.has(fingerprint)) {
      unique.add(fingerprint);
      results.push(row);
    }
  }
  return results;
}
```

This, for example, will come up with...

```
> x = [
... [ [8], [3, 2, 1], [9] ],
... [ [7], [8, 3, 9], [1, 2] ],
... [ [8], [1, 2, 3], [9] ],
... ];
> getUnique(x);
[ [ [ 8 ], [ 3, 2, 1 ], [ 9 ] ],
  [ [ 7 ], [ 8, 3, 9 ], [ 1, 2 ] ] ]
```

Obviously if your inner values are non-primitives (objects, arrays, etc) then this will fall over, but if you're dealing with numbers like your example, it should be fine.

Comment: thank you! I am dealing only with numbers, so this should be fine. I will check it with my arrays soon and post back afterwards

Comment: just checked all 3 scripts, yours returned the correct result for my reference array. thanks for it! see the jsfiddle inside my comment on the original question post

Answer (score 2):

First of all, here is a working JSFiddle for you to play around with: http://jsfiddle.net/missyalyssi/ro8o94nk/

Given an input array the function `findUnique` will return an array containing items that are unique according to your definition. So, for example:

[[8],[1,2,3],[9]] is a duplicate of [[8], [3,1,2], [9]] but it is not a duplicate of [[9], [3,1,2], [8]]

My main focus when writing this was to make it easy to read and understand.

```
function findUnique(input) {
  let found = [];
  let uniqueEls = new Set();
  let hasDup = true;
  for (let element of input) {
    hasDup = found.length && 
             found.every((el) => {return deepEqualsNaive(el, element)});
    if (hasDup) {
      uniqueEls.delete(element);
      continue;
    }
    found.push(element);
    uniqueEls.add(element);
  }
  return [...uniqueEls];
}
```

This function uses `deepEqualsNaive` to determine if two arrays are equal. Since object equality in javascript means that the arrays would point to the same memory location we need to build our own function to return true for what we are calling equal. Here, by equal we mean that they have the same elements even though they are not pointing to the same memory location, or appearing in the same order.

*I have written this function recursively for readability* I do not know the context that you are using this in. If you could overflow the stack then use an iterative version.

Here are some example inputs and what we would expect:

```
deepEqualsNaive([ [],[22],[1,13,17],[12],[] ], [ [],[22],[17,13,1],[12],[] ]) => true

deepEqualsNaive([ [],[22],[17,13,1],[12],[] ], [ [],[12],[1,13,17],[22],[] ]) => false

deepEqualsNaive([ [],[22],[1,13,17],[12],[] ], [ [],22,[17,13,1],[12],[] ]) => false
```

The function:

```
function deepEqualsNaive (input, clone) {
  if (!Array.isArray(input) || !Array.isArray(clone)) return false;
  if (input.length !== clone.length) return false;
  var result = 0;
  for (let elIdx = 0; elIdx < input.length; elIdx++) {
    var tryDeep = true;
    if (Array.isArray(input[elIdx])) tryDeep = deepEqualsNaive(input[elIdx], clone[elIdx]);
    if (!tryDeep) return false;
    result ^= input[elIdx];
    result ^= clone[elIdx];
  }
  return result === 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 for the well explained post and the obvious effort that went into it! Small note however: a bitmask is kept to compare the unordered arrays, but this has the side effect that e.g. `deepEqualsNaive([4,8],[12,0])` returns true as well.

Comment: @Me.Name Thank you ^.^ and yup you're right there is ambiguity with the bit mask

Comment: very nice! great explanation, thank you very much for this. will try it on my arrays as soon as I find the time. I am trying to find a nice elegant solution for an art project of mine, calculating different data needed

Answer (score 1):

If it's ok to have reference to the original array 'records' and inner arrays (that is, no deep copy), you can use something like:

```js
function distinct(arr){
    const res =[], //array with results
     cmpArr = (a1,a2) => a1.length===a2.length && a1.every((i,ind) => a2[ind] === i),
     cmpRec = (a1,a2) => [1,2,3].every(i=> cmpArr(a1[i],a2[i])); //compare 'records' for indices 1,2 and 3    
  for(let subarr of arr){   
    subarr[2].sort(); //NB, this alters the source array. If this is not allowed, a work around can be created
    if(!res.some(r => cmpRec(r,subarr))) //check if 'res' doesn't have an entry , based on the cmpRec function
     res.push(subarr);      
  }
  return res;
}

//test:
let input = [
  [ [],[22],[1,13,17],[12],[] ], 
  [ [],[22],[17,13,1],[12],[] ], 
  [ [],[12],[1,13,17],[22],[] ], 
  [ [11],[12],[13],[14],[15] ], 
  [ [15],[14],[13],[12],[11] ]
];

console.log(distinct(input).map(JSON.stringify));
```

Comment: thank you, this is very lean! looking good! indeed no "deep copy" needed. will try it on my arrays soon and post back ASAP!